# Closed formula for the coefficients of a series obtained from an expansion.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

The Heisenberg algebra is generated by $h_i, i\in \mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}$ and the central element $c$. We expand the function 
$$\exp (\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}h_{-n}\frac{z^n}{n}) = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}h_{-n}\frac{z^n}{n} + (\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}h_{-n}\frac{z^n}{n})^2+\cdots \\
= 1 + h_{-1} z + (\frac{h_{-2} + \frac{h_{-1}^2}{2}}{2}) z^2 +(\frac{h_{-3}}{3}+\frac{h_{-1}h_{-2}}{4} + \frac{h_{-2}h_{-1}}{4} + \frac{h_{-1}^3}{6})z^3 + \\
+ (\frac{h_{-4}}{4}+\frac{h_{-1}h_{-3}}{6}+\frac{h_{-2}h_{-2}}{8}+\frac{h_{-3}h_{-1}}{6}+ \\
+ \frac{h_{-1}^2h_{-2}}{6}+\frac{h_{-2}h_{-1}^2}{6}+\frac{h_{-1}h_{-2}h_{-1}}{6}+\frac{h_{-1}^4}{24})z^4 + \cdots .$$
Denote 
$$
\exp (\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}h_{-n}\frac{z^n}{n}) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_nz^n.
$$
Then $$P_0=1, P_1=h_{-1}, P_2 = \frac{h_{-2} + \frac{h_{-1}^2}{2}}{2}, \ldots.$$
Is there a close formula for $P_i, i \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$? Or is there a recurrence formula which can compute $P_i$? Are there some references about this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: I presume you've seen the [Bell polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials) already?

Comment: @J.M., thank you very much.